# C++ | Particle In Cell simulation for plasma physics - Poisson equation solver over a standard grid

Tags: c++, solver, poisson

I am constructing my own set of processes for the task that is ahead of me, however I am currently stuck at the 3D Poisson equation to solve potentials and magnetic fields generated by moving charged particles.

In short, Particle In Cell consists of 4 core processes:

1. Integration of movement particles (from Lorentz equation),
2. distribution of charge densities to the nodes of the grid (and current densities for magnetic fields),
3. solving of Poisson equation to compute potentials and electric/magnetic fields at the nodes of grid,
4. distribution of electric/magnetic fields to particles.

And the cycle repeats. I am able to do the steps (1), (2) and (4), but not the Poisson part. I am integrating particles by Boris scheme, grid is simply constructed as `cell[i][j][k]`, with dimensions of K x L x M and the distribution process is a little bit tricky, but not very hard after all.

However, to my big surprise, I cannot find any suitable library that will solve 3D Poisson equation via Finite Differences Method (FDM). I am starting to think that I will have to write my own solver, but solving partial differential equations is a science on itself and I was told to not try this solution, since the results may be unstable if I don't do it properly. FFT may be also a solution, but I need something that will work even if boundary conditions are not periodic.

**My question is:**

Do you know of any suitable library for C++, that will take the right hand side of Poisson equation and compute the resulting potentials? Computation has to be done via FDM. Also, right hand side of Poisson equation actually means the whole grid of K x L x M points, which is integrated over a finite differences - edges of the grid.

Is it hard to write my own solver for Poisson equation? What algorithm do you recommend?

Do you know of any other solutions? Free software, well-written paper or documentation, thesis paper, anything.

Thank you in advance, this is currently a very serious problem for me since I cannot continue in my work.

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11147/free-open-source-c-c-library-to-solve-2d-poisson-equation-using-the-finite-dif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try some library like [libmesh](http://libmesh.sourceforge.net/) or [deal ii](http://www.dealii.org/). They are made formthis kind of problems...

Comment: Thanks, I heard of deal ii. I am going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You might go for a do-it-yourself approach.
First write the system of equation that you will have to solve.

Determine how many variable you will have, for example 3 variable per cell x N cells.
Determine how many equations will link these variables.

You should have the same number of variable and number of equations, say N.

Then, see if your equations are linear. If so, you should be able to write your system as AX = B, where A is a NxN matrix, B a vector, and X contains all the variable (the unknowns) you identified earlier.

Then, solving a linear system A*X=B is rather straightforward, with MATLAB for example, or with a LU solver (C/C++ code for this is easy to find, and takes maybe 200 lines).

If your system is not linear, you may use the Newton-Raphson method. 
You must write all your equations in the form ... = 0.

Then you have to compute all the derivatives of all your equations, and put them in a so-called Jacobian matrix J.

The derivative of the equation n°i with respect to variable n°j will go in the row n°i and the colum n°j of the jacobian. That is to say J[i][j] = df[i]_dX[j].

You have to guess some initial values for all your variables in X, which should be not too far from the solution.

This guess is not the solution, so it will not result in all your equations being = 0. 
The vector that contains all these "should-be-0" values is F. F[i] is the "residue" of equation n°i;

When you have computed J and F_X, you can solve the linear system J*D = F_X. Then D contains the difference between your current variables in vector X and the solution you are looking for.

Then you compute a new X, equal to X - D.

If the system is not linear, the new X will be closer to the solution, but you have to repeat the process several times (Compute J, F_X, solve J*D = F_X, and set X = X - D) to get close enough to the solution.

This may seem too hard to setup, but in fact it is doable.

Well, in 1D this is almost easy, but in 3D boundary conditions may be tedious.

### edit

Also, you will have to choose how you express space derivatives of your variables, so you can transform your differential equations into discrete equations, AKA discretization. You can start with first-order schemes :

- df/dx = (f[i+1] - f[i])/dx
- d2f/dx2 = (2*f[i] - f[i+1] - f[i-1])/dx²